# Horrible nested if statement for changing CSS based on RadioButton selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I'm writing away for this website, and I've come into a problem. I need to display only one `td` based on the corresponding radio button pressed. However, there are two 'master' radio buttons that dictate how many radio buttons are shown, and after that, which are selected. - if that makes any sense!

Now, I am only showing a very small snippet of what I actually have at the moment - this nested if statement goes on 5 more times. So, as you can probably imagine, it looks horrendous. And I'm not sure if there is a better way, maybe there is a way to create functions that can be called? What do you all think?

```
$('input:radio').change(function () {
                if (this.id == prodMoveRadio) {
                    if ($("#ExtIdTd").is(":visible") === true) {
                        $("#ExtIdTd").css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                        $("#LocIdTd").css({ visibility: "visible" });
                        $("#" + locIdRadio).prop("checked", true);
                        $("#ExtIdTr").css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#MainContent_DetailsPanel").css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                        $("#ExtIdTr").css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                        $("#LocIdTd").css({ visibility: "visible" });
                        $("#" + locIdRadio).prop("checked", true);
                    }
                }
                else if (this.id == opMoveRadio) {
                    if ($("#ExtIdTd").is(":visible") === false) {
                        $("#ExtIdTr").css({ visibility: "visible" });
                        $("#ExtIdTd").css({ visibility: "visible" });
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#MainContent_DetailsPanel").css({ visibility: "visible" });
                        $("#" + extIdRadio).prop("checked", true);
                        $("#ExtIdTr").css({ visibility: "visible" });
                        $("#ExtIdTd").css({ visibility: "visible" });
                        $("#LocIdTd").css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                    }
                }
```

**Edit**

Would it be 'clean' to put a class onto the `td`'s I need to hide, and hide that whole class then set only the visibility to `visible` on the `td` I require? Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use polymorphism to represent the states, and to apply the needed formatting.

Comment: Reading up on them now, and they seem to be exactly what I'm after. Thank you!